# Constructor Reference in a ternary operator Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, conditional-operator

I want to replace the if-else function with a one-liner return statement, and I was wondering why I can't create an object via contructor reference  within a ternary operator?

What I would like to replace something like this:

```
public Animal createAnimal(boolean isDangerous) {
        if(isDangerous) {
          Shark shark = new Shark();  // Shark extends Animal
          return shark ;
        }       
        Cat cat = new Cat(); //Cat extends Animal
        return cat;
    }
```

This runs fine:

```
public Animal createAnimal(boolean isDangerous) {
        Shark shark = new Shark(); // Shark extends Animal
        Cat cat = new Cat(); //Cat extends Animal
        return isDangerous ? shark : cat;
    }
```

This is also working from an another part of the code:

```
Optional<Animal> animalOptional = zoo.getAnimals().stream().findAny(); //getAnimals() is returning a Set<Animal>
animalOptional.orElseGet(isDangerous ? Shark::new : Cat::new); // -> it creates me an Object depending on the boolean
```

But if I want to return an object there, I got this error message: *The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*

```
public Animal createAnimal(boolean isDangerous) {
        return isDangerous ? Shark::new : Cat::new;
    }
```

Is there a one-liner solution for the first block?

Comment: What do you think `Shark::new` gives you? A tipp: Not an instance of `Shark`.

Comment: `zoo.getAnimals().stream().findAny().orElseGet(isDangerous : Shark::new : Cat::new);` works, not sure what you're expecting?

Comment: `return isDangerous ? new Shark() : new Cat();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a one-liner solution for the first block?

Yes, you're overthinking it:

```
return isDangerous ? new Shark() : new Cat();
```

The operands of the conditional operator are only evaluated when required, so this will only create one instance.

---

> I got this error message: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

That's because you're not actually returning an `Animal`, but rather a method reference to a thing which takes no arguments and returns an `Animal`. So, you could have written (amongst other things):

```
public Supplier<Animal> createAnimal(boolean isDangerous) {
    return isDangerous ? Shark::new : Cat::new;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this is what I was looking for! `Supplier<Animal> animal = isDangerous ? Shark::new : Cat::new;` I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote :)

Comment: But you should be able too accept this answer, eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest one-liner I could think of

```java
public Animal createAnimal(boolean isDangerous) {
    return isDangerous ? new Shark() : new Cat();
}
```